# Edge chromatic number of hypergraphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, hypergraph

This is question [Selection problem in a collection of non-empty sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228126/selection-problem-in-a-collection-of-non-empty-sets) with a simplification in criterion 3.

Is there a set $X\neq\emptyset$ and a collection ${\cal F}\subseteq {\cal P}(X)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ of non-empty subsets of $X$ with the following properties?

1. $a\in {\cal F} \implies |a|\geq 2$,
2. $a\neq b\in {\cal F} \implies |a\cap b| \leq 1$, and
3. there is no function $f: {\cal F} \to X$ such that

   - if $a, b\in {\cal F}$ with $a\ne b$ and $a\cap b\neq \emptyset$ then $f(a)\neq f(b)$?

Comment: Interesting question. It's not a *Selection* problem any more since $f(a)\in a$ is not required. I'd call it "edge chromatic numbers of hypergraphs". Of course there is no such $\mathcal F$ with $X$ infinite or with $|a|=2$ for all $a\in\mathcal F.$ A projective plane won't do because the number of lines is equal to the number of points.

Comment: @bof: How do you see that you can't have $X$ infinite or $|a|=2$?

Comment: @DouglasZare If $X$ is infinite then there is an injection $i:\binom X2\to X$. If $\mathcal F$ satisfies (1) then for each $a\in\mathcal F$ we can choose $a'\subseteq a$ with $|a'|=2.$ If (2) also holds, then $a\to a'$ is an injection, and so is $a\to i(a'),$ so we can define $f(a)=i(a').$

Comment: @DouglasZare  Suppose $|a|=2$ for all $a\in\mathcal F.$ We may assume $|X|=n\lt\infty.$ Then the question is, can a graph of order $n$ have edge chromatic number greater than $n$? I.e., can the complete graph $K_n$ have edge chromatic number greater than $n$? It's an elementary result in graph theory that $K_n\ (n\gt1)$ has edge chromatic number $n$ or $n-1$ according as $n$ is odd or even. We could also cite Vizing's theorem: a simple graph $G$ has $\chi'(G)\le\Delta(G)+1$ where $\chi'$ is the edge chromatic number and $\Delta$ the maximum degree, so $\chi'(K_n)\le\Delta(K_n)+1=n.$

Comment: @bof: Thanks. The existence of that first injection is equivalent to the axiom of choice, no? I was thinking about sets whose Cartesian squares are larger, without choice.

Comment: @DouglasZare Since the OP didn't mention the axiom of choice, I took it for granted that he's working in ZFC. There is no injection $\binom X2\to X$ if $X$ is a Dedekind-finite set with at least $4$ elements. I've heard that "$|X\times X|=|X|$ for all infinite $X$" is equivalent to AC, but I don't know if that works for $\binom X2.$

Comment: @bof - that's right, I'll modify the title

Comment: This if true would generalize famous result (Fisher inequality?) that if any two sets $a\ne b$ from $\mathcal{F}$ satisfy $|a\cap b|=1$, then $|\mathcal{F}|\leqslant |X|$. Which has different proofs, including linear algebraic, but none of them is obvious. We should probably try to examine these proofs on generalizability in this chromatic direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is equivalent reformulation of Erdös-Faber-Lovász conjecture, see Wikipedia page about it.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Faber%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_conjecture

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about how the stated question is equivalent to the EFL conjecture?

Comment: It is precisely explained in Wikipedia. After introducing some notations and simple reasoning they conclude: "Thus, the Erdős–Faber–Lovász conjecture is equivalent to the statement that any simple hypergraph with n vertices has chromatic index (edge coloring number) at most n."

Comment: Oh right... brilliant thanks, Fedor!